# Export Composite Datawindow to EXCEL/CSV (PB 11.5)

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a suite of reports (~500) where some have sub-reports (another datawindow) and some do not.  I have one screen that handles viewing/printing/exporting all the reports.  The problem is the export only grabs the main report and ignores all the child/sub reports.

I'm trying to find some sample code where I can dump the main report and any of the child reports into a datastore and then export that datastore.  However, any of the examples I've found that involve getchild the column name is required.  Obviously, I need a more dynamic solution since I'm dealing with ~500 reports.

Can anyone help or offer any solutions that don't require purchasing third party tools/software/add-ons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Found in: https://scn.sap.com/thread/3805986*

Hi;

The SaveAs ( ) method only works on the immediate parent DW Object within the DW Control. Since a composite DW has many child DWO's inside it, your SaveAs command is not addressing the children.

Currently, this is the limitation of the SaveAs command for either a Nested or Composite DW. You do have a few other options ...

1) Create a Tabular or Grid DW that houses all the columns that you would like the Excel spreadsheet to see. Then populate this DW inside a hidden DataStore separately when the user requests an export of the composite DW to Excel.

2) You can access a composite DW's entire data buffers by using the DW "DOT" notation. You would have to code something like this or each child DW in the composite DW ....

Any  la_data[]
  ls_data =  DC.Object..Object.Data

Once you have extracted all the child DWO's data - you could then export it to Excel using the procedure stated in #1 or using OLE interaction with Excel. Either way, definitely some significant coding work on your part.

Regards ... Chris